# Using VBA to auto update note/comment in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("F9:N46"))
        If c.Comment Is Nothing And c.Value <> "" Then
            With c.AddComment
                .Visible = False
                .Text Application.UserName & ":" & Date & " - " & c.Value
            End With
    
        ElseIf Not c.Comment Is Nothing And c.Value <> "" Then
            c.Comment.Text Application.UserName & ":" & Date & " - " & c.Value & vbNewLine & c.Comment.Text
        End If
    Next    
End Sub
```

The problem is that if I edit a cell that is not in my defined range I get an error like this:

[image]

How can I make this work for cell F9:N46 only?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect  You have to check the value returned by Intersect before trying to iterate over it. See the example in the link.

Comment: For your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539574/vba-code-to-automatically-resize-cell-comment

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an `If` statement as shown below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F9:N46")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In Target
            If c.Comment Is Nothing And c.Value <> "" Then
                With c.AddComment
                    .Visible = False
                    .Text Application.UserName & ":" & Date & " - " & c.Value
                End With
        
            ElseIf Not c.Comment Is Nothing And c.Value <> "" Then
                c.Comment.Text Application.UserName & ":" & Date & " - " & c.Value & vbNewLine & c.Comment.Text
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```